# Countable product of completely metrizable spaces

Tags: general-topology

[Willard General topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFaVc.png)

Here is the Teorem for the countable product of completely metrizable spaces. In the first way, How does this construction give us a isometry? Is there easy solution to show that first way?

Comment: it is already easy. For any $x\in X_n$ consider the point $(a_1,a_2,...,a_{n-1},x,a_{n+1},a_{n+2},...)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the author is assuming (likely a convention throughout the book) that $\prod X_i$ is equipped with the product topology. In the product topology, for any fixed $(a_i)_i$ with $a_i \in X_i$ for each $i$, for each $n$, the map $\phi_n(x) := (a_1, \ldots, a_{n-1}, x, a_{n+1}, \ldots)$ is a homeomorphism onto its image $$X_n^* : = \{(x_1,\ldots) \in \prod X_i | x_i = a_i \text{ except for $i=n$ }\}.$$ Thus, any metric $\rho^*$ on $\prod X_i$ generating the product topology naturally defines a metric $\rho_n$ on any $X_n$ by $\rho_n(x,y) := \rho^*(\phi_n(x), \phi_n(y))$, and it is with respect to this specific metric that we can say that $(X_n^*, \rho^*|_{X_n^*})$ is isometric to $(X_n, \rho_n)$, and the function $\phi_n$ is an isometry from $X_n$ to $X_n^*$.

Edit to show $\phi_n$ is an isometry: Note that $\phi_n$ is an isometry by construction. Recall that a map $f$ is an isometry between $(X, d_X)$ and $(Y, d_Y)$ if $d_Y(f(a), f(b)) = d_X(a,b)$ for all $a,b \in X$. Let's just plug in for our situation, the condition becomes that $\rho^*(\phi_n(x), \phi_n(y)) = \rho_n(x, y)$ for all $x,y \in X_n$. But this is the *definition* of $\rho_n$, so of course it is true.

Note that the theorem in question always talks about "metrizable" spaces, not "metric" spaces. This means that the topology for the spaces is fixed, but any metric generating that topology can be used, so for the $\implies$ direction, the author is free to take a complete metric $\rho^*$ on $\prod X_i$ and then for each $n$ use the $\rho_n$ defined above as a compatible metric for $X_n$ that happens to be complete.

Comment: thank you so much, aprreciated. So How can I conclude that phi is isometry?

Comment: See my edit to my answer that shows $\phi_n$ is an isometry.

Comment: I am grateful, thanks again

Comment: You are welcome. If you believe my answer has fully resolved your question, then please consider clicking the up arrow to give positive review and the check mark to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: surely I do it:)